# Custom method in HTML Custom Element extending built-in element

Tags: javascript, html

I have registered a custom element that extends canvas:

```
class MyCanvas extends HTMLCanvasElement {
    constructor() {
        self = super();
    }

    myFunction = function() {
        console.log("HELLO");
    };
}

customElements.define('my-canvas', MyCanvas, { extends: 'canvas' });
```

I then have added it to my `index.html` with:

```
<canvas is="my-canvas" id="canvas" class="w-100" width="1600" height="900"></canvas>
```

And finally I have a js script trying to execute `myFunction` with:

```
const canvas = document.querySelector("#canvas")
canvas.myFunction() // Complains canvas.myFunction is not a function
```

What I am missing here? I tried to do stuff like:

```
MyCanvas.prototype.myFunction = function() {
    console.log("ANOTHER ONE")
}
```

With the same result. Here is a jsfiddle with the issue:

https://jsfiddle.net/do673gp5/

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Your code works fine for me: https://jsfiddle.net/bsewdym6/. Note that I did have to change `TMView` to `MyCanvas`, but I presume this is a mistake made when transposing the actual code in to the question. If it's still not working for you can you please edit the question to include a snippet which shows a full working example of the problem

Comment: Ah yes, indeed I made a mistake when I was transposing in to the question. I just edited it.

Comment: I wonder it the issue is that the part where I get the canvas and call the function:
```
const canvas = document.querySelector("#canvas");
canvas.myFunction()
```
is done in a different file than the one where `MyCanvas` is defined?

Comment: Like this: https://jsfiddle.net/do673gp5/

Comment: The issue is that (at least in the fiddle) your component script is loaded async, and it is not available yet when you call `myFunction`. If you add your check code after the element class it works. Until the registration has happened (which could happen `async` or `deferred`), no element will be upgraded and they will have their originator as the current prototype. You could probably also use a check like `await customElement.whenDefined()` (Docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CustomElementRegistry/whenDefined) and _then_ execute your method.

Comment: Aah indeed, that was the issue. Thank you!